# itunes connect ready for sale version not appearing in app store 4 days later

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I submitted updates to over 20 apps on the same day and they got approved and released on the same day.  Now all of them are listed as version 4.2.4 Ready for Sale in itunes connect, but in the app store only about half of them are showing up as 4.2.4  I've had it take a few hours before but this was 4 days ago.  Also, its showing up as the old version on every platform I try (browser, itunes, iPhone, iPad) Anyone else experienced this? Is the only way to fix this to submit another update?

Update: I removed one from sale in all territories and then turned it back on and it is now showing up with the proper version.  I am going to try that for the others and see if it fixed it...If not I will be contacting apple and will report back

2nd Update: That appears to have worked on all apps...Not sure what caused this issue I'll try and reach out to apple about this so other people don't experience it

Comment: You should make contact with some Apple developer Team members or App Review Board. Email them and let them know about your issue.

Comment: You should contact them even if this fixes your issue since this clearly is a bug in iTC.

Comment: Facing same issue